# exchange web service error - the remote server returned an error 405 method not allowed

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to send a mail via the exchange web service. I looked into the msdn and find some help.
Every time I try to run this code i'm getting the above error :(
I try read almost everywhere...

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("My user name", "my pass");

System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

service.Url = new Uri("my web service url.WSDL");
    EmailMessage appointment = new EmailMessage(service);

appointment.Subject = "Test by me";
appointment.Body = "DateTime.Now";
appointment.ToRecipients.Add("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");

appointment.SendAnd

SaveCopy();
```

Comment: Have you tried to change WebCredentials with NetworkingCredentials passing in the domain as well? And can you axess the .asmx url in a web browser?

Comment: My bad, it should be. WSDL and not ASMX. And yes, I can access it from a web browser. I don't have the NetworkingCredentials option.

Answer (score 21):

When setting the url to the service, you should in fact use the asmx, and not the wsdl link.

```
service.Url = new Uri("https://server/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

That should make it work.

Comment: Ok, I tried it. and get the following error: "The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML." This is how my code looks like now:                                                             
service.Url = new Uri("https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage(service);
mail.From = new EmailAddress("from_address@server.com");
mail.ToRecipients.Add("to_address@server.com");
mail.Subject = "Email Subject";
mail.Body = "Email Body";
mail.Send();

Comment: You should check the inner exception and see if it displays what went wrong.

Comment: Inner exception - "Root element is missing"

Comment: I don't knoe if it helps. In oreder to access the throw the web to the mailbox I use a different user name: YYYYY\XXXXX and in my program i'm using only the XXXXX. What should I use? the YYYY\XXXX Or the XXXXX or the XXXXX@GGGGGG.biz? maybe this is the problem?

Comment: YYYYY\XXXXX can be used as NetworkCredential("XXXXX", "password", "YYYYY"). Works fine in my app.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas regarding the solution?