# Setting Outlook out of office from a mobile

Tags: c#, android, ios, outlook

I've been tasked with writing a mobile app (using xamarin) that will allow you to set your Outlook out-of-office. Many of the examples I've found are using interop, which won't build within a mobile application. Can anyone recommend an alternative method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exchange Web Services to do that.

from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563356(v=exchg.140).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563356%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx): :

```
static void SetOOF(ExchangeServiceBinding service)
{
    // Identify the user mailbox for which to set OOF information.
    EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();

    emailAddress.Address = "donhall@example.com";
    emailAddress.Name = String.Empty;

    UserOofSettings OOFSettings = new UserOofSettings();

    // Identify the time that a user is OOF 
    Duration duration = new Duration();
    duration.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    duration.EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4);
    OOFSettings.Duration = duration;

    // Identify the external audience.
    OOFSettings.ExternalAudience = ExternalAudience.Known;

    // Create the reply messages.
    ReplyBody internalReply = new ReplyBody();
    ReplyBody externalReply = new ReplyBody();
    externalReply.Message = "This is my external OOF reply";
    internalReply.Message = "This is my internal OOF reply";

    OOFSettings.ExternalReply = externalReply;
    OOFSettings.InternalReply = internalReply;

    // Set OOF state.
    OOFSettings.OofState = OofState.Enabled;

    // Create the request.
    SetUserOofSettingsRequest request = new SetUserOofSettingsRequest();
    request.Mailbox = emailAddress;
    request.UserOofSettings = OOFSettings;

    try
    {
        // Send the request and return the response.
        SetUserOofSettingsResponse response = service.SetUserOofSettings(request);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Allan - thanks for your response. I finally got it working but the library seems to have been modified, so in case anyone else needs it, here's my code:

```
  ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);

        service.Url = new Uri("https://<server>/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();

        emailAddress.Address = "nick.wright@<domain>";
        emailAddress.Name = String.Empty;

        OofSettings OOFSettings = new OofSettings();

        OOFSettings.Duration = new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));

        OOFSettings.ExternalAudience = OofExternalAudience.All;

        OofReply internalReply = new OofReply();
        OofReply externalReply = new OofReply();

        externalReply.Message = "This is my external OOF reply";
        internalReply.Message = "This is my internal OOF reply";

        OOFSettings.ExternalReply = externalReply;
        OOFSettings.InternalReply = internalReply;

        OOFSettings.State = OofState.Disabled;

        try
        {
            service.SetUserOofSettings("nick.wright@<domain>", OOFSettings);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

I came across a couple of errors. Firstly, the documented URL is incorrect, so this fixed it:

[exchange web service error - the remote server returned an error 405 method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164651/exchange-web-service-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-405-method-not)

Secondly, the Exchange version needed explicitly setting (although once set, I could set it to any version and it worked!?!)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/df5c0c5e-1ea6-4ee9-824c-e8cb4930e291/ews-managed-api-error-exchange-server-doesnt-support-requested-version?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Comment: got to the bottom of it. The code I posted will work if using the Exchange Web Services API, but the code Allan posted will work when adding a web reference to the Web Services. A case of reading too much documentation from too many sources!